# nPlot in rCharts does not work with addControls

Tags: r, bar-chart, nvd3.js, rcharts

Hello everyone reading this.

I am trying out R with knitr and rCharts to generate Rmd -> md -> html files with flashy plots. At the moment I am trying out nPlot wrapper and I cannot get addControls feature working for some reason. Here is my simple example:

````
```{r testing, include=T, results='asis', comment=NA, message=F, echo=F}
cData <- read.csv("~/USCrime2012.csv")
crimebarPlots = nPlot(ViolentCrime ~ State, data = cData, type = "discreteBarChart")
crimebarPlots$xAxis(rotateLabels = -90)
#crimebarPlots$addControls("y", value = "ViolentCrime", values = names(cData[,-1]))
crimebarPlots$print("test", include_assets=T, cdn=T)
```
````

Everything works while the commented line is left out, but once I include it the plot stops working - all I get is an empty drop-down list button with no labels.

I adopted this example from here: http://bl.ocks.org/patilv/raw/7968210/ where it's presented to be working fine. I got the data from [HERE](https://www.google.lt/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDIQFjAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdl.dropboxusercontent.com%2Fu%2F56796392%2FUSCrime2012%2FUSCrime2012.csv&ei=pYABU4_5GaOWyAHeroCQAw&usg=AFQjCNFB9uDBAOHwpKxfoxXe4PjevCWHSQ&sig2=Jsw7G5XW_mW08TV10EKPhg&bvm=bv.61535280,d.aWc&cad=rja)

Before doing this I tried to run it with my own dataset with the same kind of result.

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated.

-KK.

Comment: That is expected. The `addControls` method has not been implemented for all libraries. It only works for `nvd3`, `polychart` and `dimple`.

Comment: Reading your post again, I am confused. Are you using `nPlot` or `hPlot`?

Comment: I am using nPlot (mistake in the title, not the code. sorry about that). Corrected now.